# Recorrer ArrayList con diferentes objetos java

Tags: java, arraylist, herencia

Tengo una clase `Avisos` de la que heredan dos tipos de avisos. Los guardo todos en un ArrayList y no conseguía acceder a los getters de uno de los avisos hijos.

Necesito obtener los avisos del tipo `AvisosLimpiar` en una fecha determinada y estoy utilizando el siguiente código para recorrer el ArrayList:

```
 for(Object av : listaDeAvisos){
            if( ((AvisosLimpiar) av).getDia() == diaInicial){
                System.out.println("Datos del aviso...");
            }
}
```

No conseguía acceder a los getters de la clase hija hasta que usando Netbeans ha autocompletado con `(AvisosLimpiar) av)`. y he conseguido acceder, pero no entiendo que hace exactamente este código.

Cómo puedo acceder a métodos de las clases hijas?

Edit: Código según solución:

```
for (Avisos av : listaDeAvisos) { 
    if (av instanceof AvisosLlamada) {
        AvisosLlamada avLLamada = (AvisosLlamada) av; 
        if ((avLLamada.getDia() >= diaInicial && avLLamada.getHora() >= horaInicial) || (avLLamada.getDia() <= diaFinal && avLLamada.getHora() <= horaFinal)){ 
            System.out.println("Aviso del día " + avLLamada.getDia() + " hora " + avLLamada.getHora());
            System.out.println("Habitación: " + avLLamada.getHabitacion());
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No puedes acceder a los métodos de `AvisosLimpiar` y de "`OtroAviso`" (no especificas el nombre de la clase, llamémosle así de aquí en más) porque tu variable de iteración está definida como `Object` y `Object` no tiene esos métodos

Si tu `listaDeAvisos` es una lista de `Avisos` deberías recorrerla de la siguiente manera, definiendo tu variable de iteración del tipo `Avisos`, de modo que puedas invocar los métodos definidos en la clase padre.

```
for(Avisos av : listaDeAvisos){
     av.someMethod(); // invocaciones a metodos definidos en Avisos
}
```

Para acceder a métodos de las clases hijas, puedes [castear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289393/casting-variables-in-java), pero para eso debes asegurarte previamente que el tipo del elemento coincida con la clase a la que casteas, de lo contrario obtendrás una excepción al tratar de castear un elemento al tipo incorrecto.

Eso lo puedes realizar utilizando el operador [instanceof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526817/use-of-instance-of-in-java), el cual retorna `true` cuando la variable a la que se le aplica es del tipo explicitado y false de lo contrario.

```
for(Avisos av : listaDeAvisos){
     if(av instanceof AvisosLimpiar){
          AvisosLimpiar avl = (AvisosLimpiar) av;
          avl.metodoDeAvisoLimpiar(); // ahora puedes invocar métodos de AvisosLimpiar
     }else if(av instanceof OtroAviso){
          OtroAviso oa = (OtroAviso ) av;
          oa.metodoDeOtroAviso(); // ahora puedes invocar métodos de OtroAviso
     }
 }
```

> netbeans ha autocompletado con (AvisosLimpiar) av). y he conseguido acceder pero no entiendo que hace exactamente este código.

En realidad si ejecutaste el código y no tuviste excepciónes es porque tu lista tenía objetos solo del tipo `AvisosLimpiar` y el casteo que realizaste en tu condicional (`((AvisosLimpiar) av).getDia() == diaInicial`) pudo ser efectuado. El codigo que implementaste castea cada `Aviso` a `AvisosLimpiar`-

Comment: Efectivamente, en cuanto añadí un aviso del otro tipo dio una excepción. con instanceof se soluciona. Lo de los parentesis me imaginaba que era para hacer casting pero no lo tenía claro. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya funciona correctamente y me ha quedado el código más limpio:

Comment: for (Avisos av : listaDeAvisos) {
            if (av instanceof AvisosLlamada) {
                AvisosLlamada avLLamada = (AvisosLlamada) av;
                if ((avLLamada.getDia() >= diaInicial && avLLamada.getHora() >= horaInicial)
                        || (avLLamada.getDia() <= diaFinal && avLLamada.getHora() <= horaFinal)) {
                    System.out.println("Aviso del día " + avLLamada.getDia() + " hora " + avLLamada.getHora());
                    System.out.println("Habitación: " + avLLamada.getHabitacion());
                }
            }
        }